# Impersonation in DevOps

Tags: .net, azure-devops, tfs-sdk

I am using TFS/DevOps .Net client library (soap based) to interact with DevOps.

However I am having problems to impersonate as another user, and DevOps always return me an error:

> UserX needs the following permission(s) to perform this action: Make
>   requests on behalf of others

This is despite I have assigned this permission to the user in one of the collection groups under organization settings in DevOps. I have even added this user as a member of the Project Collections Administrator.

Is there any other permissions I need to grant or is there a specific collection group where I need to assign this permission?

Edit to add codes. Below are the codes I am using. Additional note, the code is working fine with on-prem TFS and I am using PAT to authenticate. The user we are trying to impersonate is a user in our Azure AD.
It just wouldn't work when we try with DevOps. The code will fail at the second `EnsureAuthenticated()` call:

```
var configurationServer = new TfsConfigurationServer(new Uri("https://xxxx"),
    new VssCredentials(new VssBasicCredential(
        string.Empty,
        "xxxxxx"
)));

configurationServer.EnsureAuthenticated();

var identityService = configurationServer.GetService<IIdentityManagementService>();

// Look up the user that we want to impersonate
TeamFoundationIdentity identity = identityService.ReadIdentity(
        IdentitySearchFactor.AccountName, "xx@xx.xxx", MembershipQuery.None, ReadIdentityOptions.None);

var impersonatedconfigurationServer = new TfsConfigurationServer(new Uri("https://xxxx"),
    new VssCredentials(new VssBasicCredential(
        string.Empty,
         "xxxxxx"
    )), identity.Descriptor);

impersonatedconfigurationServer.EnsureAuthenticated();
```

Thanks.

Comment: Can you share the code?

Comment: Having the exact same issue attempting to migrate some customizations from on-prem Azure DevOps Server to cloud Azure DevOps services.  After a lot of searching, I've yet to find an answer.  I'm guessing impersonation is just not enabled in the cloud services. Some relevant links on impersonation:

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/405699/impersonation-in-azure-devops.html

Comment: And another link: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/239344/vsts-impersonation-issue.html

Comment: Solution for Azure DevOps Services that allows creation of work items in another user's name with no impersonation: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64877721/425465